# why are /media and /home /mnt/home so large?

Tags: linux-mint, disk-usage, external-hdd, root-filesystem

I am trying to get hplip-3.14.10 on a desktop. I found out that the setup returns a `make command failed with status code 2` which is caused by insufficient disk space.

I used disk usage analyzer to find out what is taking up all the space.

[image: disk usage]

I see /media is taking up 12,5gb. How should I read this picture? Is there 12,5gb of disk space used in /root for the external hdd (hdd-2 200gb) drive? And why is that?
It is an *external* usb drive which is mounted in /etc/fstab.

Secondly I notice that the /home directory is twice in the list.
First just as /home

and directly below that line as a sub-directory of /mnt.

is this the same /home directory mentioned twice? (the sizes are different, especially the directory 'nel' is larger).

Or do I have 2 /home directories right now?

**update 1**: the output from `df -h`,the output from `ls -ld /home` and `/etc/fstab`:

the output from `df -h`:

```
nico@dell-desktop ~/Downloads/hplip-3.14.10 $ df -h
df: ‘/root/.gvfs’: Toegang geweigerd
Bestandssysteem Grootte Gebruikt Besch Geb% Aangekoppeld op
/dev/sda2           12G      11G  371M  97% /
udev               367M     4,0K  367M   1% /dev
tmpfs               75M     928K   74M   2% /run
none               5,0M        0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none               374M     6,6M  368M   2% /run/shm
overflow           1,0M      92K  932K   9% /tmp
/dev/sdb1          115G      12G  103G  11% /media/HDD2-200GB
/dev/sda3          5,4G     4,5G  635M  88% /mnt/home
```

the output from `ls -ld /home`:

```
nico@dell-desktop ~/Downloads/hplip-3.14.10 $ ls -ld /home
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 mei 12 18:42 /home
```

the ouput from fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

proc    /proc   proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=6e00ca13-1769-43ef-886b-4eaedb7ab1cd       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
#UUID=6c25053b-618a-45f5-af50-97c7cd5c40c3      /home   ext4    defaults        0       2
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=200CF32C0CF2FB9A   /media/HDD2-200GB       ntfs-3g defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=nl_NL.UTF-8        0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=c2043080-eb69-47ad-8728-4c254e325d6c       none    swap    sw      0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8        0       0
```

**update 2:**
I have now deleted sda3 in gparted and removed the home directory under /mnt
I now have to merge the free space from sda3 to sda2.
However, I have to boot gparted from cdrom or usb in order to perform this operation, and I cannot do that using teamviewer right now.

Comment: First Off, don't compile source on a binary based Distro.  Instead, [go here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install.html), which [leads to the Automatic Installer](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html).  Is this what you're using??

Comment: Hi, I used the automatic installer which returned the status 2 code. Because I did not know what that means, I went searching and came on the launchpad site where someone suggested to go into the hplip directory and use the 'make' command. I did so and the saw the error message saying there was insufficient space.

Comment: Disconnect your USB Drive as Dope Suggests below, and update your post with the results of whats left in `/media`

Comment: Please don't post images of textual output, paste the actual text...

Comment: i tried, but because I control the machine using teamviewer, I cannot paste the text, so a screenshot was my only option actually. I will replace the image with the text anytime soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/media/` is a stub where most modern distributions mount removable media when they are plugged in, e. g. USB hard drives, optical media, flash drives, etc.  One of them you have mounted is identified as `HDD2-200GB` which is appearing as a 12.5GB filesystem, which is full.

`/mnt`/ is another stub which is generally used for permanently mounted filesystems.  These can usually be found in `/etc/fstab` (the **f**ile**s**ystem **tab**le).

If I had to guess, your `/home/` directory or partition was backed up to another device mounted to `/mnt/home`; I would have guessed that you just had `/home` as a symlink to `/mnt/home`, but as you say, the sizes are different.

You might want also to take a look of the output of `df -h`, which will more clearly break things down by filesystem, rather than path.  Since filesystems can be mounted at (just about) any arbitrary path, that can be less potentially confusing than a nested-tree view.

Also, `ls -ld /home` will show you whether `/home/` is an actual directory, or a symlink pointing elsewhere.

Comment: thanks! I will use your suggestions. Because of the limited size of the internal hard disk, I wanted to have a symlink to the /home on the external harddisk. But as far as I know, I never got that far. This situation reminds me of that. Without the +/- 5gb which is in /home right now on my internal harddisk, I would have enough space. I will checkout if I need the /home or can simply work with a symlink to the /mnt/home. That leaves me with only the first point: the external drive is 200gb, not 12,5 gb. And does it count for the size of /?

Comment: That last is kind of a touchy question, since `/` is a special cast- it is the root node for the entire filesystem tree.  That's one reason I wanted to see `df -h`'s output - it breaks things down more readably.  `/media/HDD2-200GB` is showing as a 115G partition, of which 12.5GB is in use.  I'm not sure why the GUI program was showing it as full.